# Django - form object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and working on forms. I got this error message

```
  File "C:\Users\foo\what\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\foo\what\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\foo\what\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 108, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404 and self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_price = models.IntegerField()
    product_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photos', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    def get(self, request):
        a = Product()
        return a
```

forms.py

```
class UploadProduct(ModelForm):
    product_name = forms.TextInput()
    product_price = forms.NumberInput()
    product_photo = forms.FileInput()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_name', 'product_price', 'product_photo']
```

views.py

```
def uploadProduct(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UploadProduct(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect(upload_product_ok_page)
    return render(request, 'upload_product.html', {'form': UploadProduct})


def upload_product_ok_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

urls.py

```
    path('upload_product/', Product),
    path('upload_product/', views.uploadProduct, name="upload_product"),
    path('', views.upload_product_ok_page, name='upload_product_ok_page'),
```

upload_product.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'upload_product' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I made sure I imported the correct functions, classes and objects.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you define a `get` method on a model returning the model and using this as substitute for a view?

Comment: You're right I forgot to delete it. But now I ended up getting the error 'Product' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: For the error 'Product' object has not attribute 'get', I think it should be `{'form':UploadProduct()}` in render of `uploadProduct` view.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it's still the same error.

Comment: fro what im seeing  i think you have some unnecessary urls here, i think you should remove path('upload_product/', Product), and path('', views.upload_product_ok_page, name='upload_product_ok_page'), especially path('upload_product/', Product)

Comment: Try mentioning the name of view in quotes, instead of actual view in `redirect` as `return redirect('upload_product_ok_page')`.

Comment: ok i will officially add ab answer now @Angela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fro what i'm seeing you have some unnecessary urls here, i think you should remove the following

```
path('upload_product/', Product),
path('', views.upload_product_ok_page, name='upload_product_ok_page'),
```

especially

```
path('upload_product/', Product),
```